# Normalize contacts in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a chat application with a login. I am using MySQL database for storing the user data. My table is called `userData`. It contains:

```
userID*
userPass
firstname
surname
role
contacts
```

OK, so this system is for staff and students and users are able to add contacts to their list. I am struggling to structure my database to store the contacts efficiently. Basically I am not sure how to normalize with the contacts column.

For example...

`userID*  userPass  firstname  surname  role     contacts
1234     2012      Sponge     Bob      Student  1345
1234     2012      Sponge     Bob      Student  3421
1234     2012      Sponge     Bob      Student  1445`

Would it be appropriate for me to create a table for each userID to store the contacts? I am making this in JAVA using a MySQL db. Would be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have two tables, one with user data and other with contacts. This can then be joined by using the shared identifier.

```
CREATE TABLE userData (userID int primary key, userPass varchar(32), firstname varchar(32), surname varchar(32), roleID int);
CREATE TABLE roles (roleID int primary key, rolename char(32));
CREATE TABLE contacts (userID int, contactID int);
```

I threw 'roles' in there as an example. You can then join these as necessary, e.g:

```
SELECT contacts.* FROM contacts 
JOIN userData USING (userID)
WHERE userData.userID=1234;
```

Or to take if further and benefit from the normalization:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ud.firstName,' ',ud.surName),
       CONCAT(cd.firstName,' ',cd.surName)
 FROM contacts
 JOIN userData AS cd on (cd.userID=contacts.contactID)
 JOIN userData AS ud on (ud.userID=contacts.userID)
 WHERE
  contacts.userID=1234;
```

Comment: would this contacts table only hold contacts for userID 1234? or will it accomodate for every user... osrry i seem to be getting more and more baffled!! :'(

Comment: Yes, this contacts table would be able to hold contacts for all users. `userID` column would have the 'owner' of the contact while `contactID` would be user ID of the contact. `userData` has name and other details for all users.

Comment: `SELECT` statements are there to show you how to list contacts for one single user. You could of course omit the `WHERE ...` clause and it'd show all contact pairs.

Comment: to make it easier for myself if I created a query from my java application to create a table called 1234 named after the user and stored all of user 1234's contacts in there would that be bad practice? and thanks for the sql fiddle very useful

Comment: Yes, having a table per user for this kind of a use would be bad practice.